# merging xlsx files in java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, apache-poi

i m trying to merge two .xlsx files to each other in java. But i m somehow getting a NullPointerException on the line

```
     if (cell.getSheet().getWorkbook() == mcell.getSheet()
                        .getWorkbook()) {
}
```

Any ides what could cause this error ? when i tried before merging other two files, my code worked perfectly, but now i changed the files and now getting NullPointerException. The new Files which i try to merge have 2 sheets. I just need to merge the first pages of them.

Here is my code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            FileInputStream excellFile1 = new FileInputStream(new File(
                    "/Users/TLQ/Desktop/a.xlsx"));
            FileInputStream excellFile2 = new FileInputStream(new File(
                    "/Users/TLQ/Desktop/b.xlsx"));

            // Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
            XSSFWorkbook workbook1 = new XSSFWorkbook(excellFile1);
            XSSFWorkbook workbook2 = new XSSFWorkbook(excellFile2);

            // Get first/desired sheet from the workbook
            XSSFSheet sheet1 = workbook1.getSheetAt(0);
            XSSFSheet sheet2 = workbook2.getSheetAt(0);

            // add sheet2 to sheet1
            addSheet(sheet1, sheet2);
            excellFile1.close();

            // save merged file
            File mergedFile = new File(
                    "/Users/TLQ/Desktop/Albert.xlsx");
            if (!mergedFile.exists()) {
                mergedFile.createNewFile();
            }
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(mergedFile);
            workbook1.write(out);
            out.close();
           // mergeThemAll(mergedFile);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void addSheet(XSSFSheet mergedSheet, XSSFSheet sheet) {
        // map for cell styles
        Map<Integer, XSSFCellStyle> styleMap = new HashMap<Integer, XSSFCellStyle>();

        // This parameter is for appending sheet rows to mergedSheet in the end
        int len = mergedSheet.getLastRowNum();
        for (int j = sheet.getFirstRowNum(); j <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); j++) {

            XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(j);
            XSSFRow mrow = mergedSheet.createRow(len + j + 1);

            for (int k = row.getFirstCellNum(); k < row.getLastCellNum(); k++) {
                XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(k);
                XSSFCell mcell = mrow.createCell(k);

                if (cell.getSheet().getWorkbook() == mcell.getSheet()
                        .getWorkbook()) {
                    mcell.setCellStyle(cell.getCellStyle());
                } else {
                    int stHashCode = cell.getCellStyle().hashCode();
                    XSSFCellStyle newCellStyle = styleMap.get(stHashCode);
                    if (newCellStyle == null) {
                        newCellStyle = mcell.getSheet().getWorkbook()
                                .createCellStyle();
                        newCellStyle.cloneStyleFrom(cell.getCellStyle());
                        styleMap.put(stHashCode, newCellStyle);
                    }
                    mcell.setCellStyle(newCellStyle);
                }

                switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
                    mcell.setCellFormula(cell.getCellFormula());
                    break;
                case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                    mcell.setCellValue(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                    break;
                case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    mcell.setCellValue(cell.getStringCellValue());
                    break;
                case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                    mcell.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK);
                    break;
                case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                    mcell.setCellValue(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                    break;
                case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:
                    mcell.setCellErrorValue(cell.getErrorCellValue());
                    break;
                default:
                    mcell.setCellValue(cell.getStringCellValue());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`row.getCell(k)` can return `null` if there is no `Cell` at that position. There are a few ways to work around the problem (e.g. asking the workbook to create cells on the fly), but for this case, checking against `null Cell`s is the easiest and least resource-consuming option.

Comment: thanks for your response. I m not sure if i understood correctly but i added a try catch block in my code. But now i m getting here a NullpointerException ; for (int k = row.getFirstCellNum(); k < row.getLastCellNum(); k++)